# Flow raises error when assigning `null` to a property of an interface but not to an equivalent variable

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Can someone explain why this works:

```
const foo: number | null = null;
```

And the following does not? For me they are the same, but Flow found some error.

```
interface Bar {
  foo: number | null;
}

const bar: Bar = {
  foo: null,
}
```

```
// Error
27:   foo: null,
           ^ Cannot assign object literal to `bar` because null [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `foo`.
References:
27:   foo: null,
           ^ [1]
23:     foo: number | null;
             ^ [2]
```

[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJysg3gKGcmAe0IC5kQBXAWwCNpkAfcigGxYG4cBfHHBQkAGcwyGhjLpMAXmx4CxMpTYAabkA)

Comment: Looks like a bug - if you change `interface` to `type Bar = { foo: number | null; }` it works as expected

Comment: I can’t explain why `interface` gives an error, but what you really want in this case is just a normal [object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/) alias, like the one in @AlekseyL.’s comment. Flow [interfaces](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/) are only meant for working with instantiated classes, not with objects you create with object literal syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only), "interface properties are invariant by default." We can see that this results in an error if trying to assign an object literal to a typed variable,

```
interface Invariant { property: number | string }

var value1: Invariant = { property: 42 }; // Error!
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgG5ysO5kDeyADlAPbHRgCeAXMiAK4C2ARtMgD7IDOYOIAObIAvgCgxWKMiwAbRhACM9dFNz4AvIRLlKUGvQAsAJlEBuZAHpLyAKJRyUAIRA)

However, the property can be modified after assignment,

```
interface Invariant { property: number | string }

function method1(value: Invariant) {
  value.property;        // Reading works!
  value.property = 3.14; // Writing works!
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgG5ysO5kDeyADlAPbHRgCeAXMiAK4C2ARtMgD7IDOYOIAObIAvgCgxMRiARhgZEMmYQwACzIATAIwAKLABtGEeuiw48YAJSExyZAaMA6UhSrUA3Ha9eA9D+QAShBwGqDCAO5kUADWPACEtvZwhhDO5JRQNMgAvMgAzI5aACyefsgA6jhyQsiRMfFiIkA)

In your case, you could write

```
interface Bar { foo: number | null };

function method1(bar: Bar) {
  bar.foo = null;
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJysg3smB7PALmRAFcBbAI2mQB8TSAbR5AXwG4AoTmUkBMMDwhk5CGAAWeACYBGABSUMxdFACU2TsmRKoAOnx5kAXgbMurIA)

You could also `implement Bar` for a class and assign the `foo` property

```
interface Bar { foo: number | null };

class X implements Bar {
  foo: number | null;

  constructor() {
    this.foo = null;
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJysg3smB7PALmRAFcBbAI2mQB8TSAbR5AXwG4AoThRuAZ37IAGsmDkADowjkI4IekxZOyXAWJkqNemWZcVyBHhD8wUUgjB4oACgCU2A6rAALYPwB0+PMgC8DPQNWTlYgA)